# CSV file export cell

Tags: csv, append, export, stringbuilder

So I have this app that takes listview and export to device as .csv file.
This is the code

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : array) {
                sb.append(s.trim()).append(",");
            }
            result = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1).toString();
        }
```

I'm happy with the output since it's organized the way I intended to. The problem was if the data has comma "," it recognized it (i think) and put it on another cell. But when I change the append to another "sign", it totally ruin it.

Heres the picture of two output.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BazVv.png)
The first one is okay because I didn't use comma. On the second one on the other hand I reversed the full name so I used comma.

What do you think I do with this one?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your CSV with something else that you know will not be in your columns like ->  **;** <-

To do so, you will select the cells -> right click -> format cells -> custom -> @ -> OK

After that you should export your CSV file and you will see that now the columns are separated by -> ; <- and not -> , <-

And then on your code replace the  **,** for the **;**